# I need to make around 3000 API requests to facebook Graph API for collecting insights data. Facebook sets rate limiting to its API calls

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-multiprocessing

I need to make around 3000 API requests to Facebook Graph API for collecting insights data. Facebook sets rate limiting to its API calls. I am currently using python's multiprocessing module and grouping the requests into pools of 50 requests each. 
I get a connection error when I send the requests after it processes some requests successfully.

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

```
#my multiprocessing pools
pool= mp.Pool(processes = len(s))
    results= [ pool.apply_async(get_data, args=(url,)) for url in s]   
    data = [p.get() for p in results]

#get data function to send requests
def get_data(url):
    data = requests.get(url,params=parameters).json()
    return(data)
```

I am using an access token which has a validity of 2 months. Is there any way to make 3000 calls without the connection being denied by facebook.

Comment: 3000! It sounds very unlikely that you genuinely need to make this many calls. The answer is almost certainly going to be to find a way to do what you want with fewer calls to the API. If you're fetching the same data over and over again you might want to think about caching the responses for a while.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Answer (score 1):

I recommend listening to the advice listed on [Facebook's Rate Limiting page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting). Spread out your requests over time and ensure that you are not making unnecessary requests.  A local instance of memcached is great for application-level caching or run varnishd in a docker container if you can exploit HTTP caching.

I've solved similar problems by having the application react to a rate limit response by stopping sending requests for a period of time.  Once you hit a rate limit, pause for a period of time, then send a single request.  If the request is successful start sending requests at a low rate and increase the rate of requests slowly.  If the single request is still rate limited, then pause for a little longer before trying again.

This is essentially a scheduling problem and not a concurrency problem.  Your application becomes a little more complicated because you need to be able to control the rate of requests.  I would consider using [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) for request & response queues and [multiprocessing.Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event) to control whether workers are actively sending requests or not.  When one of the workers hits a rate limit, clear the "sending" event and set a separate event that will trigger a separate sub-process to process requests from the queue and perform the "pause and request" cycle until you are no longer being rate limited.  Then you can flip the "sending" event which will release the workers to run.